# Which is the best database connection mechanism to be used for an Android app?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am new to android development, a noob precisely. i started android just last year and i am so confused on what database connection mechanism  type to be used with my android for its Login and Signup Functions. i have searched online and came across couple of methods like (SQlite, MySQL, Volley, etc...) but i don't know which is better to learn and integrate with my Android APP.

So if anyone can just help me out with making this choice!

Also, links to documents, tutorials or any relevant resource would be appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: This question is best asked in other Stack Exchange sites .. SO is code-only related ...  Request to move to appropriate forum.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately you just asked one big vague / opinion based question which isn't appropriate for this site. As you are a self identified as 'new' to Android, I would look at various online tutorials (search for 'udacity android' for one where Google had a hand in it). Once you've got a specific programming question, come back here.

Comment: For real Zak?? i had no idea.... admin should do something on it if required, all i need is a solution. thanks Zak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite Database.
Since it is available on the device itself, I think its the best. You will have less headache about it, It's easy, lightweight, no need to include any libraries.

Several advantages of SQLite

- Content stored in an SQLite database is more likely to be 
  recoverable decades in the future, long after all traces of the
  original  application have been lost. Data lives longer than code.
- If you have data related with each other, file will not allow you to
  relate them. At that time SQLite will help you.
- SQLite has higher
  performance

Comment: Awesome.. I actually thought about using sqlite. But what if I want to get the ID from a db table on my website to login to the Android app.. Is it possible with sqlite?